# If Non EU citizen with Blue card become unemployed, can he get back to student status again?

Tags: germany, blue-card, residence-cards

If a Non-EU citizen with Blue card and pursuing master degree simultaneously. In case he becomes unemployed, can he get back to student status again in case Blue card is of 1year?

Answer (score 1):

I think if you still enroll in some universities that should be doable. Or if you stay longer than 7 years in Germany (study years calculate as half) then u can apply for the niederlassungserlaubnis.